# Blocking findAndModify in Ruby MongoDB Driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb, queue, mongoid

I'm trying to achieve something like this in MonogDB:

```
require 'base64'
require 'mongo'

class MongoDBQueue

  def enq(thing)
    collection.insert({ payload: Base64.encode64(Marshal.dump(thing))})
  end
  alias :<< :enq

  def deq
    until _r = collection.find_and_modify({ sort: {_id: Mongo::ASCENDING}, remove: true})
      Thread.pass
    end
    return Marshal.load(Base64.decode64(_r["payload"]))
  end
  alias :pop :deq

  private

    def collection
      # database, collection & mongodb index semantics here
    end

end
```

Naturally enough I want a Disk-backed queue in Ruby that doesn't destroy my available memory, I'm using this with the Anemone web spider framework which by default uses the `Queue` class, there's a fork which can use the `SizedQueue` class, however when using a `SizedQueue` for both the "page queue" and "links queue", it often deadlocks, presumably because it's trying to dequeue a page and process it, and it's found new links, and that situation cannot be reconciled.

There's also an existing implementation of a Redis queue, however that also exhausts all my available memory on this machine (Available memory is 16Gb, so it's not trivial)

Because of that I want to use this MongoDB backend, but I think the implementation is insane. The `Thread.pass` feels like a horrible solution, but Anemone is multi-threaded, and MongoDB doesn't support blocking reads, so it's a tricky situation.

Here's my references:

- Redis queue implementation for anemone: https://github.com/chriskite/anemone/blob/queueadapter/lib/anemone/queue/redis.rb
- MongoDB findAndModify: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

Questions:

- Can anyone comment about how sane this is, compared to `sleep` (which             should trigger the VM to pass control to the next thread, anyway, but `sleep` feels dirtier)
- Should I perhaps `Thread.pass` and `sleep`? ( I guess not, see above)
- Can I make that read from MongoDB block? There was talk of that here, but never came to anything: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/rqnHNFXaZ0w

Comment: What makes you think that MongoDB doesn't support blocking reads?  If you do a find_one() or a find_and_modify(), the operation won't return until the query is complete & the result is back at the client.  You'll need to do "Safe Mode" writes in order to have blocking writes.

Comment: William, how would one change the above code to be a blocking read? (I define blocking as not returning until a result satisfies the query)

Comment: simply doing   >>  until _r = collection.find_and_modify({ sort: {_id: Mongo::ASCENDING}, remove: true}) <<
should be blocking  -- just in that thread, of course

Comment: Seems to be William, been working more on that and the code is at https://github.com/leehambley/ruby-persistent-queue-classes - the MongoDB one isn't passing all of the tests yet, but the Redis one is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

1) Reads in MongoDB are blocking.  If you do a findOne() or a findAndModify(), the call will not return until the data is present in the client side.  If you do a find(), the call will not return until you get a cursor: you can then iterate on the cursor as much as you need.

2) By default, writes to MongoDB are "fire and forget".  If you care about data integrity, you need to do either safe writes by setting :safe => true in your connection, database, or collection object

Answer (score 0):

Kernel.sleep is actually a better solution, as otherwise you'll spin there (albeit passing control to other threads after each query).
As the findAndModify is atomic, only one thread (even on JRuby) will take the job, so I don't quite understand what's the "blocking" issue here.

Comment: I don't want to sleep, at all - I want to "stop" and wait for that query to return a document, if there are no documents, I want to STOP THE THREAD here and make sure it does not return until there is one. I want to avoid sleeping, since the shortest time one can sleep is 0.1s in Ruby (reliably.) is an unnecessary overhead of time. I want Mongo not to return from that call until a document matches that query.